# How can I make a multithreading queue-system for incoming lines from a socket in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, queue

I'm fairly new to Python and I have a code that receives information from a socket and processes each line one after one in a queue-system. The problem is that if a line ever take an unusual amount of time to process, all the other lines in the queue will have to wait.

How can I make it so that ones a new line is received, it will process it with a thread, and make a new thread for every other line regardless if the first thread has finished? I have looked at many other examples with multithreading and queues but I just don't know how I can implement something like this into my code. Any suggestions?

Here is how my queue-system currently looks like:

```
while 1:
    readbuffer = readbuffer + s.recv(2048)
    temp = string.split(readbuffer, "\n")
    readbuffer = temp.pop()

    for line in temp:
        *code processing line*
```

Comment: The terminology you're using indicates that solving this problem requires knowledge of the problem itself rather than just python programming. What you seem to be asking for is a strategy for concurrency; and that could be implemented in other programming languages as well. I think the simplest way to deal with your problem is to time the first process and switch to another one if it takes too long and then do the same again. Just go through all the processes giving them each a maximum time for each cycle and just repeat doing that until they're all done.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, the low-level threading API suffices. (For more ambitious tasks, see the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/threading.html#module-threading) module.)

```
try:
    from _thread import start_new_thread
except ImportError:
    from  thread import start_new_thread

def process(line):
    #*code processing line*
…
for line in temp:
    start_new_thread(process, (line,))
```